# Very simple root of complex polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I came across this question today and was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

Let $P(z) = z^8 - \frac{5}{2}z^4 + 1$.  Suppose $\omega$ is a root of $P$, show $i\omega$ and $\dfrac{1}{\omega}$ are also roots of $P$.

Well $i\omega$ is fine since

$$ P(i\omega) = (i\omega)^8 - \frac{5}{2}(i\omega)^4 + 1$$
$$ P(i\omega) = \omega^8 - \frac{5}{2}\omega^4 + 1 $$

However I'm unsure where to start with

$$ P\bigg(\frac{1}{\omega}\bigg) = \bigg(\frac{1}{\omega}\bigg)^8 - \frac{5}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{\omega}\bigg)^4 + 1$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\omega^8 P(\omega^{-1}) = 1 - \frac{5}{2} \omega^4 + \omega^8 = P(\omega) = 0.
$$
Since $\omega^8 \neq 0 $ it must be the case that $P(\omega^{-1}) = 0$.

Comment: So simple!  Thank-you.